# IOS Keychain Automatic Login after logged in

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, restful-authentication, keychain

Fully understand the username and password should be stored in a keychain wrapper, but should a social app confirm if the keychain values are set and then init home page, or should it confirm the credentials are correct over an restful api call in the delegate?

Apps like twitter and facebook are very fast in launching the home page after logged in, so I assume they just check to see the key chain values are not null.

Help appreciated on best approach.